# Android ActionbarSherock - new project doesn't recognize the Theme.Sherlock.Light

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a new project and it doesn't recognize the first line of this snippet in my styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I did set up ActionbarSherlock in my code base. But I forgot how to make a new project recognize it.
Any idea what I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're starting a NEW app, I'd recommend going with ActionBarCompat rather than ABS, check out `<your local android-sdks folder>/samples/android-15/ActionBarCompat/src/com/example/android/actionbarcompat/MainActivity.java`for an example

Comment: @Blundell What is that new thing that you mention? I have never hered of it

Comment: It's brand spanking new from Google, it is their new ActionBar and has been added to the latest version of the support library. It basically means Jake Wharton *may* be more likely to stop supporting ABS, he has always said it was deprecated from inception

Comment: @Blundell Thank you, and grrrrr...I just figured out ABS :)

Comment: It's in support v7 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html yeah but think of all the ppl you can help when you are ABC king!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would Right click on your project go to properties, select android on the list at the left and at the bottom of the window you would use the add button to add library into your project.